# RxJS - fix type of combineLatest result

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I come across this often in Angular when I work with `combineLatest` to combine 2 observables that emit optional values.

The basic pattern is this:

```
const ob1: Observable<Transaction[] | null>;
const ob2: Observable<Price[] | null>;

const currentValue = combineLatest([ob1, ob2]).pipe(
  filter(([a, b]) => !!a && !!b),
  map(([a, b]) => {
    // Here the type of both and a and b is nullable
    const x = a.map(a => a.id); // This gives compilation error that a can be null
  });
```

I want to do work in the `map` function to combine the events once both observables emit non null values.

The `filter` does indeed filter but the type of each element is still `T | null`.

I want the type to be `Transaction[]` for `a` and `Price[]` for `b` without using `a!` or `b!`.

This pattern repeats a lot in my code and I would like to find a solution that is short and elegant and does not require me to write boiler plate code for each use case.

I found some answers [how to fix this for a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999777/filter-undefined-from-rxjs-observable/62971842#62971842). But how do I do this for a tuple or array?

Answer (score 0):

How about simple casting? Add another `map` to pipe after `filter`: `map(([a,b])=> [a,b] as [Transaction[], Price[]]),` or even cast it inside your `map` body.

Comment: That would work but since I use this pattern a lot, I am looking for something less verbose. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999777/filter-undefined-from-rxjs-observable/62971842#62971842) but that works for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Creating two types of your required tupple will help you to solve your problem.

```js
        function filterNullish<T, K>(): UnaryFunction<Observable<[T |null, K | null]>, Observable<[T, K]>> {
          return pipe(
             filter(([a, b]: [T |null, K | null]) => !!a && !!b) as 
             OperatorFunction<[T |null, K | null], [T, K]>
    );
}

        const currentValue = combineLatest([ob1, ob2]).pipe(
            filterNullish() ,
            map(([a, b]) => {
                const x = a.map(a => a);
                const y = b;
                return x;
            })).subscribe((r) => console.log(r));
```

Comment: And the question is - how to create `R` out of `V` automatically (with mapped types or similar) instead of having to create it manually for each use case.

Comment: And the answer is updated. I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: this is what I did but of course it works only for tuples with 2 elements. I am looking for a generic solution for arbitrary number of elements.